# Need ILMerge hint

Tags: .net, asp.net, ilmerge

I'm trying to merge vintasoft barcode sdk with my data access dll and it's not working after ilmerge. Any ideas are welcome

here is the error:

```
IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.]
2.┌.©(Byte[] param0) in :0
2.┌..cctor() in :0

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '2.┌' threw an exception.]
2.┌.¥Σ() in :0
Vintasoft.Barcode.WriterSettings..cctor() in :0

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Vintasoft.Barcode.WriterSettings' threw an exception.]
Vintasoft.Barcode.WriterSettings..ctor() in :0
Vintasoft.Barcode.BarcodeWriter..ctor() in :0
_Default.buttonGenerateBarcode_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\ILMergeSample\WebBarcodeWriterDemo\QRBarcode.aspx.vb:27
System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e) +0
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +110
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow/faq).

Comment: What, specifically, isn't working -- your code, the third party code? What have you tried to diagnose the problem? What error messages/exceptions are you getting? Why do you need to use ilmerge? Have you tried any alternatives to merging? -- Updating you question to include this information will help us give you answers.

Comment: After merging the assemblies, making instance of the barcode writer throws exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to merge an obfuscated assembly. Chances are good, it wont work at all.

Answer (score 3):

Like leppie said, merging obfuscated assemblies usually leads to problems.

One alternative is to stick the offending dll into an embedded resource, and load it from there using

```
byte [] bytes = Resources.SomeAssemblyDll;
Assembly.Load(bytes);
```

We do it on demand in our AppDomain's assembly resolver:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new 
    ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
```

where we test what assembly the framework is looking for, and if needed load it from the embedded resource.