# ILMerge doesn't work with .NET 1.1

Tags: .net-1.1, ilmerge

I try to merge two .NET 1.1 assemblies and use them in app. Exception occurs during app compilation:

Error   1   Metadata file 'c:\Source\ILMergeTest\App\Merged.dll' could not be opened -- 'Version 1.1 is not a compatible version.'  C:\Source\ILMergeTest\App\App\CSC   App

Exception isn't related with libs content. It occurs even if libs are empty.

Where is trouble?

Are there alternative ways to merge .NET 1.1 assemblies?

Thanks.

Comment: Use /targetplatform:v1.1 maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `/targetplatform` command line switch.

For example, `ILMerge.exe /targetplatform:v1.1`

Comment: I know about this parameter. I tried to use /targetplatform:v1.1 and /targetplatform:v1. But nothing helps. I tried to use last version of ILMerge. It doesn't work with 1.1 at all. Throws IndexOutOfRangeException exception during merge. I want to try different ILMerge versions but I don't know where to download them.

Comment: What is the full stack trace of the error message?  Make sure your assembly is not obfuscated.  See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601357/need-ilmerge-hint